# Windows 10 RTM (10240 or higher) idle high CPU Usage at 20% - 22% with Bootcamp MBP

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, boot-camp, cpu-usage

I Just upgraded to Windows 10 10240 as an insider tester finding that this upgrade keeps my CPU Usage at 20%-22  range. 
I also made a clean install from latest ISO and the problem persist.

Is someone having this problem too? If you have some advice It could be really helpful. Thanks.

Edit 2:
Including a picture of the xperf utiltity. ACPI.sys was the module with problem.
So After putting on the laptop on sleep and wake up, the system is normal. So I think is a problem with the Intel drivers or something like that.

**Edit 3:
The workaround is to put laptop on sleep and resume it. That worked for me in the last 3 years.**

[image: my Task Manager]

[image: this is after filtering the xper]

Comment: Can you open up task manager and post a screenshot of what process(es) are contributing to that constant 20-22% CPU usage?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that: the process is System but using process explorer it says ntoskrnl.exe is the process with the problem.

Comment: Did you install all supporting software/drivers?

Comment: Yes. I also created the USB from Bootcamp assistant which install everything.

Comment: There are no Boot Camp drivers for Win 10 yet. Until there are, all bets are off. https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721?locale=en_GB

Comment: These error wasn't on the 10162 version of Win10. So I think this is something different on the latest version

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the CPU usage and share the trace: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: I will try this night. But found that I've put the laptop to sleep and when it woke up, the process was normal. That's very weird.

Comment: you have ACPI.sys usage. This is hard to debug. have you added a HDD caddy? if yes, look if the caddy has a switch and if yes, change the position. If you don't have a caddy, look if the CPU doesn't overheat. Try to increase CPu fan speed.

Comment: I think is the Graphic Drivers that Intel released for Windows 10. I will uninstall it and then install the one for W8.1. Thanks. Note: No new HDD or hardware.

Comment: which Intel HD do you have? I have no issue with my older HD4000

Comment: I have the Iris Pro 5200 releaded in 2013 with MBP Late 2013. Until now the problem persist even after updating the drivers. The workaround: put laptop on sleep and then wake up.